# Is it possible to show the attribution of a layer in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, attribution

I'm working with QGIS 3.22.10-Białowieża. In my project, I'm using the ESRI Satellite tile basemap (through Quick Map Services plugin), which I would like to credit in the map.

I've seen nothing about attribution among the variables section of the map and I can't find anything useful through a Google search. Is it possible to automate that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `layer_property('layername','attribution')`. Use it together with `array_to_string(layer_property('layername','attribution'))` to display the array as string. But: Not all layers provide this. Seems like ESRI Satellite does not. But for example OpenStreetMap does.

[image]

Properties you can use ([from the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#layer-property)):

- name: layer name
- id: layer ID
- title: metadata title string
- abstract: metadata abstract string
- keywords: metadata keywords
- data_url: metadata URL
- attribution: metadata attribution string
- attribution_url: metadata attribution URL
- source: layer source
- min_scale: minimum display scale for layer
- max_scale: maximum display scale for layer
- is_editable: if layer is in edit mode
- crs: layer CRS
- crs_definition: layer CRS full definition
- crs_description: layer CRS description
- extent: layer extent (as a geometry object)
- distance_units: layer distance units
- type: layer type, e.g., Vector or Raster
- storage_type: storage format (vector layers only)
- geometry_type: geometry type, e.g., Point (vector layers only)
- feature_count: approximate feature count for layer (vector layers only)
- path: File path to the layer data source. Only available for file based layers.